# How to save last Linux (Ubuntu) terminal output to text file without re-running command

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, twitter

I'm a newbie to using Linux shell and would be grateful to have your help.

I've just run a MySQL query from the command line in Ubuntu 14.04 to join two tables with 4 million rows which took me `5hrs 30mins` to execute.

```
mysql> SELECT tweets.UserID, TweetID, City, State, Tweet 
FROM users JOIN tweets 
ON users.UserID = tweets.UserID;
```

However, I forgot to send the output to a file i.e. add `INTO OUTFILE '/JoinedTable.txt` at the end of the code. Thus, it was only displayed on screen after execution.

As it took THAT long to process I'm not looking forward to running it again but would be glad to just save the entire output directly from screen to a text file without re-running the query.

Your suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on users.userId or tweets.userId ?

Comment: @e4c5 I don't have any index they are just 2 simple tables - 'tweets' table has 4 columns - UserID, TweetID, Tweet, Date while 'users' table has UserID, City & State.

Comment: no wonder it took you five hours. Create an index!!

Comment: Thanks @e4c5 I have just done that now...hopefully it should the query will run quicker now.